# MySQL schema for table of hashes

Tags: mysql

I need to store, query and update a large amount of file hashes. What would be the optimal mysql schema for this kind of table? Should I use a hash index eg.

`CREATE INDEX hash_index on Hashes(id) using HASH;`

can I reuse the PK hash for the index ? (as I understand, the "using hash" will create a hash from the hash)

Comment: "Most MySQL indexes (PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, INDEX, and FULLTEXT) are stored in B-trees. Exceptions: Indexes on spatial data types use R-trees; MEMORY tables also support hash indexes; InnoDB uses inverted lists for FULLTEXT indexes".  source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html   with other words you can't create a HASH index on a "normal" table

Comment: the "create index" command works but it seems to create a btree index. I was wondering what would be the optimal schema for such a table.

Comment: The scary bit is how you represent variable length paths, not the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File hashes are fixed-length data items (unless you change the hash type after you have created some rows). If you represent your file hashes in hexadecimal or Base 64, they'll have characters and digits in them. For example, sha-256 hashes in hex take 64 characters (four bits in each character).

These characters are all 8-bit characters, so you don't need unicode. If you're careful about filling them in, you don't need case sensitivity either. Eliminating all these features of database columns makes the values slightly faster to search.

So, make your hashes fixed-length ASCII columns, using ddl like this:

```
    hash CHAR(64) COLLATE 'ascii_bin'
```

You can certainly use such a column as a primary key.

Raymond correctly pointed out that MySQL doesn't offer hash indexes except for certain types of tables. That's OK: ordinary BTREE indexes work reasonably well for this kind of information.